# Specify real path in YAML file

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file that has a directory path (templates). I would like the tilde to represent where ever the real path of where the app is being executed.

```
test@devvm:/usr/local/superloop$ cat lib/database/templates.yaml 
---
- hardware_vendor: juniper 
  type: vfirewall
  opersys: junos
  templates:
     - ~/superloop/lib/templates/hardware_vendors/juniper/junos/vfirewall/system.jinja2
     - ~/superloop/lib/templates/hardware_vendors/juniper/junos/vfirewall/snmp.jinja2
```

The app could be installed in a home directory, or a /usr/local/ directory. In other words, it's dynamic. How do I do that?

Is it similar to `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` for when I load the YAML file?

Comment: Does it have to be a tilde? `~/` is usually used to represent the home directory and `./` is used for the current directory. If those paths were changed to './' relative paths, I wouldn't be suprised if `os.path`did the right thing already.

Comment: Thanks @Holloway, '.' did work..

Answer (score 2):

It's common to use environment variables within YAML files, like this:

```
- hardware_vendor: juniper 
  type: vfirewall
  opersys: junos
  templates:
     - ${MY_PATH}/superloop/lib/templates/hardware_vendors/juniper/junos/vfirewall/system.jinja2
     - ${MY_PATH}/superloop/lib/templates/hardware_vendors/juniper/junos/vfirewall/snmp.jinja2
```

This way, if you set $MY_PATH before calling the program that uses the YAML file, all the normal YAML parsers out there will substitute the variable for you based on what is in your env at runtime. So you can do things like `export`ing that variable to the shell that's running the program, or, for a shorter-lived (more dynamic) solution, do something like `MY_PATH=/something/over/here ./my_executable_that_processes_yamls`.

Comment: Thanks Sara. I will give it a shot!

Comment: Sweet! I used this in Pandoc configuration file ; this helps a lot to have dynamic configuration.